# Update item in sharepoint list from subission in a different sharepoint library

Tags: 2013

im currently making a DSE risk assessment form.  In the old format there is a labour intensive trail that updates personal records (stored in a SharePoint list) once a risk assessment is created, checked and verified.

As I am redesigning this I am looking for a way to automatically update the personal records with the submission dates, and if any action is required (All from fields within the form)to the new library.  This could be done from a field within the form I think.

If this is possible it would save a considerable amount of time, and be much more efficient.

Is there any way to make this happen using workflows, for example within SharePoint designer?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: can you explain a bit more. I am not getting, you want to update list when document uploaded in single library or multiple libraries?

Comment: there are two libraries, one contains personal information, including a section of if they have completed the risk assessment, when and if any further action is required.
and there is another library containing the submitted form, when the form is submitted I would like this to automatically fill the information in the 1st library containing personal information, to say the dates it was completed

Comment: Are they both document libraries, or is one of them a list? I can roughly visualise how to do what you want with a workflow, but there is one important question: what is the 'key' field by which two records in seperate places can be linked i.e. some field that is always the same for both, and is always unique?

Comment: Both are lists, and it seems like a great way to reduce the manual trail.  Im slightly confused what you mean about the "key" field, could this be the submitted date of the Risk assessment form.  otherwise i dont think there is currently any link between the two lists, can it still be done if this is the case?

Comment: Updating the fields is fine in a workflow but when a workflow goes to another list it needs a 'lookup' value to find the related item; this lookup should only ever return one result or you'll end up updating multiple items. Generally this would be some sort of ID number, but essentially there has to be a value on BOTH items that is both a) always the same for both and b) unique to each item in both lists.

Comment: Essentially what you're saying to the workflow is 'find the item in List B where Field X matches the value of Field Y on the item in List A (that I am currently processing)'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but there should be some relation between these two lists. If we talk in terms of database, there is a concept of **Foreign Key**.

So, if you are not having any relation/look up column, in that case, we need to have a column from which workflow can identify: the record has to be modified. Otherwise, it will update all/none of the items in the the destination list.

If you are having look up column or a unique value column from which workflow can identify the record that has to be updated, then this is possible and below is the procedure to update list item on creation/updation on another list item:

Step 1: Create a designer workflow on the source list.
[image]

Step 2: Add **Update an Item** action.
[image]

Step 3: Select the destination list. in this example **Likes** is the destination list.

[image]

Step 4: Add the column which you want to update.
[image]

Step 5: In this example we are updating **End Date**.
[image]

Step 6: Updating **End Date** with **Modified Date**. This can be change according to your requirement.

[image]

Step 7: Also you add more columns.

[image]

Step 8: Now you had to select the filter on which we are comparing both the lists/records. Means which is the column which is having same and unique values on both the lists.

[image]

Step 9: In this example we are considering **ID** as unique for both. These fields can be changed according to your requirement.

[image]

Step 10: Hit Ok.

[image]

Step 11: Write transition stage of workflow.

[image]

Step 12: **Go to**

[image]

Step 13: Publish the workflow.

I hope the above will help you updating the list item.